# How to serve static content using Webflux?

Tags: spring-webflux, static-content

I am learning webflux and I would like to know how to serve static content on a MicroService using webflux but I didn´t find information to do it.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 2.0 or are ou bootstrapping webflux yourself?

Comment: Hi Brian, I am using Spring Boot 2.0 with Webflux. I would like to have the reactive features from Webflux but in the same app, has the opportunity to serve some static files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
RouterFunction router = resources("/**", new ClassPathResource("public/"));
```

**UPDATE:** Don't forget to specify a name of the static file in the URL when accessing it from outside, like `localhost:8080/index.html`

Comment: It is important to end resource path with slash (`/`) so it is considered a root for resources tree. Can also use `new FileSystemResource("path/")` to serve from user's filesystem.

Comment: Where is this method `resources()`? I am bootstrapping myself not using Spring Boot.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla you can found it inside `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server`

Comment: That is it! Thanks! Note: just don't forget to specify a name of your static resource in the URL, like,  localhost:8080/index.html

Answer (score 15):

Juan Medina is right. I just want to make it even more clear and provide a [reference link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-web#!/xh).

In fact, you just have to add a RouterFunction bean to handle static resources. You don't have to implement your own RouterFunction because 
`RouterFunctions.resources("/**", new ClassPathResource("static/"));` gives what you want.

All I do is to add this piece of code:

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> staticResourceRouter(){
    return RouterFunctions.resources("/**", new ClassPathResource("static/"));
}
```

Whatever unrecoginized requests will fall into the static router.

Comment: in which class should I put this function?

Comment: any @org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration annotated class for a typical spring application

Answer (score 7):

### Spring Web Flux & public static web resources configuration

- put public static web resources into the **`public-web-resources`** folder:

  ```
  ./src/main/public-web-resources
  ```
- configure **Spring Boot 2.0**, [`application.yaml`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

  ```
  spring.main.web-application-type: "REACTIVE"
  spring.webflux.static-path-pattern: "/app/**"
  spring.resources.static-locations:
    - "classpath:/public-web-resources/"
  ```
- configure **maven-resources-plugin**, [`pom.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html):

  ```
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.1</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>copy-resources</id>
                      <phase>validate</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <resources>
                              <resource>
                                  <directory>src/main/public-web-resources</directory>
                                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                              </resource>
                          </resources>
                          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/public-web-resources</outputDirectory>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  ```

Comment: **Note**: you must not have `@EnableWebFlux` annotation if specifying the `spring.webflux.static-path-pattern`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks wildloop worked for me with following properties:

```
spring.webflux.static-path-pattern: "/**"
spring.resources.static-locations: "classpath:/public-web-resources/"
```

Spring boot adds following log line:

```
15:51:43.776 INFO  Adding welcome page: class path resource [public-web-resources/index.html] - WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WelcomePageHandlerMapping.<init>
```

And it works as welcome page for http://localhost:port/myapp/

Wish there was a way to invoke it on `/myapp/docs`

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to host static content outside of the `.jar` executable. With spring boot mvc you can just create a `public` directory next to the `.jar` and it will serve the files for you. With spring webflux that is not the case. The solutions mentioned here only works if you place the static files in the `resources/public` folder and then build the `.jar`.

I got spring webflux to serve static content without including it in the jar with the following config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-cloud-gateway
  webflux.static-path-pattern: "/**"
  resources.static-locations: "file:public/"
```

Wit this you can build the webflux `jar` and add the static files later on deployment.