# What is the function of the @EnableWebFlux annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, freemarker, spring-webflux

I have a very simple webflux demo application with freemarker which has got following files:

**1.WebFluxDemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebFluxDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebFluxDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Controller
    class HomeController {
        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String hello() {
            return "index";
        }
    }
}
```

**2.index.ftl**(located under classpath:/templates)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**3.application.yml**(without any configuration)

**4.pom.xml**(with `spring-boot-starter-freemarker` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux`)

I can get normal page via `http://localhost:8080/hello` using these files, but if I add `@EnableWebFlux` to `WebFluxDemoApplication`, there's an error shows **`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'index'.`**

I notice that the [Spring WebFlux's official guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-view-freemarker) states to use `@EnableWebFlux` to configure freemarker. Actually it works for template files, but there seems something wrong with static resources.

For example, I put a `main.js` file under `classpath:/templates/js/`, and add `<script src="/js/main.js"></script>` in `index.ftl`, then I get an error says **`WARN 3046 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [GET http://localhost:8080/js/main.js]: Response status 404 with reason "No matching handler"`**

**UPDATE**
For static resources problem, I found a solution which is to add a `RouterFunction` that resolves the static resources as the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622053/how-to-serve-static-content-using-webflux) stated.

Comment: I just ran into this myself, with the static resources. There is an open Spring issue right now, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9785. I ended up working with this commit, https://github.com/koju/nepse-data/commit/00bd1d6e3d81807a3760ef677e5d70c91c41f0d2 to get started. I haven't added in JS yet, but that got the main index.html working.

Comment: If without `@EnableWebFlux`, all static resources can be loaded. I'm afraid the case is different with the issue...

Answer (score 10):

As stated in [the Spring Boot reference documentation, `@EnableWebFlux` will tell Spring Boot that you wish to take full control over the WebFlux configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux-auto-configuration) and disable all auto-configuration for this (including static resources).

`@EnableWebFlux` doesn't configure Freemarker, it actually sets up the whole WebFlux infrastructure. In the case of Spring Boot, adding the `spring-boot-starter-freemarker` as a dependency (and optionally configuring it through configuration properties) is all you need.

Comment: If so, I think the name of `@EnableWebFlux` itself is confusing -- it not enables the webflux function but disables all auto-configuration...

Comment: EnableWebflux is a Spring Framework annotation that you can use to set up a WebFlux application from scratch. Spring Boot is doing that for you. There is no auto-configuration in Spring Framework. I know things can be confusing when looking at the documentation, so feel free to suggest changes by creating a Spring Framework or Spring Boot issue on their respective trackers.